# How to connect two models (through associations?) in Rails 3.2 and refer them in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a simple model association. I have an 'issues' table and a 'statuses' table. Every issue has a status. Table 'issues' has a 'status_id' column.

issue.rb

```
belongs_to :status
```

status.rb

```
has_many :issues
```

issues/index.html.erb

```
...
<% @issues.each do |issue| %>
...
<td><%= issue.status.title %></td>
...
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

**SOLUTION:
Create all models associations BEFORE adding any records into the database (i.e. using scaffold).**

Comment: post your solution as an answer and select it for your question's answer so the other members can see this question has already been answered , thanks

Answer (score 2):

`undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass` means `issue.status` is `nil`.

You could do something like

```
<%= issue.status.title if issue.status %>
```

Comment: Thanks @santhosh. Looks like issue.status was indeed nil because the couple of issues I tested with, were added to the database before doing the model associations. I deleted the old entries and everything works.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Mehran. Looks like I have to wait 7 more hours before answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Create all models associations BEFORE adding any records into the database (i.e. using scaffold).